# Bash script for archiving log files

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to write a script which will rename and archive log files but I just can't figure it out. Here is an example of how it should work: If you have a file named error_log and you run your script for a first time it should rename the file error_log to `error_log.1` and then archive `error_log.1` with gzip. The second time you run your script you will have two files: error_log and `error_log.1.gz`, now you should rename `error_log.1.gz` to `error_log.2.gz`; `error_log` to `error_log.1` and once again archive `error_log.1` to `error_log.1.gz` with gzip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is named `logrotate`, it's a basic `Unix` administration command to rotate the logs like you'd like.

See  `man 8 logrotate`

Example of a simple configuration file :

```
/var/log/apache/error_log {
        daily
        rotate 90       # keep only 90 logs
        copytruncate    # don't stop apps, but copy log
        compress        # gzip log in *.gz
}
```